# Draggind data points and submitting values

Tags: charts, draggable, jqplot

On page [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/customHighlighterCursorTrendline.html) there is an example of dragging data point on jqPlot chart.

How can I submit (e.g. with jQuery ajax) to server changed values? Are changed (current) values stored somewhere in jqplot object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hardest thing here is knowing when the user drags a point, not getting the data afterward.  I recommend you use a postDrawSeries hook like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // set up plot
  $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

  s1 = [['23-May-08',1],['24-May-08',4],['25-May-08',2],['26-May-08', 6]];

  plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1',[s1],{
     title: 'Highlighting, Dragging, Cursor and Trend Line',
     axes: {
         xaxis: {
             renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
             tickOptions: {
                 formatString: '%#m/%#d/%y'
             },
             numberTicks: 4
         },
         yaxis: {
             tickOptions: {
                 formatString: '$%.2f'
             }
         }
     },
     highlighter: {
         sizeAdjust: 10,
         tooltipLocation: 'n',
         tooltipAxes: 'y',
         tooltipFormatString: '<b><i><span style="color:red;">hello</span></i></b> %.2f',
         useAxesFormatters: false
     },
     cursor: {
         show: true
     }
  });

  // add our hook, to fire after a series update
  $.jqplot.postDrawSeriesHooks.push(updatedSeries);

  function updatedSeries(sctx, options) {
    console.log(plot1.series[0].data); //data for the series is here
  }

});
```

Output on every drag is (containing the updated data point):

```
[
Array[2]
, 
Array[2]
, 
Array[2]
, 
Array[2]
]
```

[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/Fzwzj/1/)  (You'll have to cache the jqPlot js files in your browser since they do not allow hotlinking.)

You'll have to implement some sort of timer to wait for 5 seconds or so before calling your ajax since the postdrawseries hook fires on EVERY drag event.  That shouldn't be too hard though.

Comment: Very nice! I tested it (http://jsfiddle.net/Fzwzj/23/) and I have only one more question. Is it possible that user would be able drag the some point only in y-axis (it's important that he shouldn't move data point from one date to another, he'd be able only to change the value)

Comment: @TOUDIdel, that's actually one of the options: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-dragable-js.html (see constrainTo)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with **postDrawSeriesHooks** is that it runs the entire time you are clicking on the graph. This could be a real mess if you are making ajax calls. I would bind the **jqplotClick** event to your chart instead. You can even get to specific point or you can save all of the data each time. But it will only get saved once per click.

```
$("#chart1").on("jqplotClick", function(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor) {
    if ( neighbor ) {
        // specific point that has been clicked
        console.log('x:' + neighbor.data[0] + ' y:' + neighbor.data[1]);
    }
    // all the data from this plot's single series
    console.log(plot1.series[0].data);
});
```

Here an example with multiple graphs that makes an ajax call to a php file every click and stores all the data points from both graphs. This only allows for a single series for each plot though.

```
var plots = [
    $.jqplot('chart1', [s0], graph_opts),
    $.jqplot('chart2', [s1], graph_opts)
];
$("#chart1, #chart2").on("jqplotClick", function(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor) {
    var data = [];
    $.each(plots, function(key, plot) {
        data[key] = plot.series[0].data;
    });

    var ajax_opts = {
        url:      ajax_info.url,
        type:     'post',
        async:    true,
        cache:    false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action:  'store_graphs',
            data:    data
        },
        success: function( response ) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function( xhr, textStatus, e ) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    $.ajax(ajax_opts);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer really helped us.

I noticed there is another hook, jqplotDragStop.

So by using this, we can call ajax every time the dragging stops. Just what we were looking for.

```
$('#chart1').bind('jqplotDragStop',
  function (seriesIndex, pointIndex, pixelposition, data) {
  // do your stuff here
});
```

Hope this helps (Sorry, could not figure out how to add a comment, new to stackoverflow).