# jqPlot with constrainTo - get dragged point value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, draggable, jqplot

I have used`dragable` option, restricting dragging to a single axis using `constrainTo`, while plotting a graph on all the series.

```
series: [{
    dragable: {
        constrainTo: 'y',
    }
}, {
    dragable: {
        constrainTo: 'y',
    }
},
....
]
```

Now, I want the new value of the point which is being dragged and the series too so that I will know which series to update. I found few questions related to my need.

1. [[jqplot]Get the point index when dragged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480201/jqplotget-the-point-index-when-dragged)

   ```
   $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataClick',function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {});
   ```

   though the question is about drag, the given answer is for `click` event using `jqplotDataClick` which won't work in my case
2. [Jqplot - How do get array back from already created graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742486/jqplot-how-do-get-array-back-from-already-created-graph)

   ```
   $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDragStop',function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
       console.log(chart.series[0].data);
   });
   ```

   this is about getting the whole series data after drag. this might work well when you have only one series and limited data set. In my case, I'm dealing with multiple series and each series contains nearly 100 data points.
3. [Draggind data points and submitting values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717347/draggind-data-points-and-submitting-values)

   this, again, summarize the above two but with an extra option `postDrawSeries`.

So, is there any way I can get

1. dragged point value
2. dragged series details.

Note: when `constrainTo` is used, `pointIndex` in the callback function gives the poistion of the mouse but the dragged point details. Ex. Suppose Im dragging `(2, 100)` and my mouse poision is, say `(10, 200)`. As I'm using `constrainTo` on `y-axis`, the actual point value is `(2, 200)` but what I'm getting in `pointIndex` is mouse position i.e. `(10, 200)`.

you can check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fzwzj/133/) here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't find any official docs to back up my answer, however from looking at the [Draggable source](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.dragable.min.js), there appears to be a `jqplotDragStart` event which has parameters `seriesIndex` (the index of the series containing the dragged point) and `pointIndex` (the index of the dragged point within the series).

I've implemented this event handler assigned these parameters to Javascript variables when dragging is started:

```
var draggedPointValue;
var draggedSeriesValue;

...

$('#chart1').bind('jqplotDragStart',function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {   
    console.log('started dragging point ' + pointIndex);
    console.log('started dragging series ' + seriesIndex);
    draggedPointValue = pointIndex;   
    draggedSeriesValue = seriesIndex;   
});
```

They can then be accessed by your `jqplotDragStop` function:

```
$('#chart1').bind('jqplotDragStop',function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
    console.log(draggedPointValue);
    console.log(draggedSeriesValue);
    console.log(pointIndex);
    //console.log(plot1.series);
});
```

You will still have to get the new 'y-axis' value from the `yaxis` attribute of the `pointIndex` parameter of the `jqplotDragStop` function.

I've created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8x5m86Lt/2/) to demonstrate this.